How can I change the available processors for a local Jmeter execution?
I am trying to execute a Jmeter script locally on my machine. At the moment it only runs with 1GB memory and 1 available Processor (see logs below).
2024-04-02 12:13:22,123 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
2024-04-02 12:13:22,123 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =1
The goal is to be able to configure both settings.


Max memory - you can amend it by either setting HEAP environment variable like:
 set HEAP=-Xmx2G && jmeter.bat

or by editing this line in JMeter startup script
 set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m


Available Processors - it reads Runtime.availableProcessors() property, if you want more - upgrade your CPU, if you want less - use -XX:ActiveProcessorCount directive


More information: 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure
